# Can I get a Selection from an Inactive Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can:

```
Workbooks(WBInactive).Sheets(SHInactive).Activate
rowNum = Selection.Row
```

but is there a way I can get the rowNum without having to `.Activate` ?
If I try:

```
rowNum = Workbooks(WBActive).Sheets(SHActive).Selection.Row
```

I get the error:

[image]

Comment: Short Answer: No. Is really based on the selection by the user? or does your code select that range earlier and you want to go back to it?

Comment: By definition, there's no [`Selection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection) on an inactive sheet.

Comment: If you really need to keep track the selected range on a worksheet done by the user, maybe use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to save the range in a public variable?

Comment: @ScottCraner Previous Selection by User, who then selects a different Sheet or Workbook

Comment: then see my second comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner if you make your Comments an Answer, I will select it.

Comment: ^ Pun intended???? :-)